# Running vmlinux ELF under QEMU

Tags: arm, qemu, firmware

I have a vmlinux ELF file to run under QEMU.

My arguments to **qemu-system-arm.exe** are:

- the correct *-cpu* argument
- the **versatilepb** *-machine* which I'm not sure if it's the right choose, but can't see the other options with *-cpu help*
- the *-kernel* flag to pass the vmlinux file
- the *-serial stdio -nographic* flags with *"console=ttyAMA0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0"* kernel arguments.

Why I don't see any output? I also tried the *-D* flag to get a log file.

Comment: Can QEMU run a vmlinux? I thought it took the bare Image/zImage. Either way, what machine is your kernel built for? You need to be emulating the thing it expects to be running on - picking something at random which might have different peripherals and a different memory layout, is highly unlikely to work.

Comment: It's true that I'm in doubt with versatilepb, but as I understand I have no much options so at least I hoped to see some error, but nothing. About the image, what is the bare image against vmlinux?

Comment: I wouldn't count on getting anything at all out of the wrong machine: if memory's in a different place to what the kernel code expects, it's going to crash and burn very early; if the UART is at a different address, and/or is an incompatible model, any attempts to output anything will go nowhere. Both of those things are quite likely. By (z)Image I mean the stripped raw binary which you would boot on a real machine (found in arch/arm/boot/ after building a kernel), as opposed to the intermediate vmlinux ELF.

Comment: Can you direct me to a specific file, in a running Ubuntu for example? As far as I know, the bootloader jumps to the vmlinuz file or bzImage, this is what you mean? If so, should I pass an image like this as the QEMU kernel argument?

Comment: Here is a minimal runnable example that just works: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/762bb78d89d1359c01a7ecee37e3f8132a48c1ce#qemu-buildroot-setup